# Python - ToggleButton - Possible to cancel the callback during once time?

Tags: python, button, gtk

I have a toggle button constructed like this:

```
self.bouton = gtk.ToggleButton()
self.bouton.connect("clicked", self.fonct)
```

In my program, I'm using

```
self.bouton.set_active(False)
```

In order to deactivate the button, but I would like to **disconnect the callback** using the above command. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try it, do you get any errors, if so what are the errors?

Comment: No errors, but the button has multiples fonctions, and I would like to reset the button once the first fonction has been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really isn't a nice solution, but:

```
self.bouton.disconnect_by_func(self.fonct)
self.bouton.set_active(False)
self.bouton.connect("clicked", self.fonct)
```